# Why Spring Config Server can't resolve localhost?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I set up a new Config Server for my project but it can't be setup locally. I just want to run it locally and make the other apps get configurations from it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

config-server/resources/bootstrap.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server

  profiles:
    active: native

  cloud:
    config:
      #uri: http://localhost:8888
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          uri:
        native:
          search-locations: config
```

```
2023-11-25T20:53:03.924+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] c.d.c.ConfigServerApplication            : The following 1 profile is active: "native"
2023-11-25T20:53:04.237+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=a1f3278e-547c-3c6c-8489-6b79cb735e9c
2023-11-25T20:53:04.394+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2023-11-25T20:53:04.401+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-11-25T20:53:04.401+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-11-25T20:53:04.473+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-11-25T20:53:04.474+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 541 ms
2023-11-25T20:53:05.775+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2023-11-25T20:53:05.861+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
2023-11-25T20:53:06.903+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2023-11-25T20:53:06.912+03:00  INFO 6340 --- [           main] c.d.c.ConfigServerApplication            : Started ConfigServerApplication in 5.908 seconds (process running for 6.345)
```

Localhost returns "Whitelabel Page" or something so it the app doesn't run.

config-server/pom.xml:

```
        <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

parent-proejct/pom.xml:

```
<modules>
        <module>user-management</module>
        <module>order-management</module>
        <module>service-discovery</module>
        <module>config-server</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).